# How to change passed parameter type in Android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I am new in Mobile Development. I am trying to pass parameters from one Activity to another with intent. But in the second activity I cannot use it because of the Type miss-match. I get it as String but I should use it as TextView. Can you please say where I did mistake?

First Activity

```
class ShowProfileActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var fullnameTv: TextView
    private lateinit var nicknameTv: TextView
    private lateinit var locationTv: TextView
    private lateinit var emailTv: TextView
    private lateinit var bioTv: TextView

    // todo load from sp
    private val mockUser: User? = User("test ", "test", "test@gmail.com", "Italy", "test, this is a mocked bio")

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_profile)

        fullnameTv = findViewById(R.id.asp_user_name_tv)
        nicknameTv = findViewById(R.id.asp_user_nickname_tv)
        locationTv = findViewById(R.id.asp_user_location_tv)
        emailTv = findViewById(R.id.asp_user_email_tv)
        bioTv = findViewById(R.id.asp_user_bio_tv)


        // init views with user data
        fullnameTv.text = mockUser?.fullname
        nicknameTv.text = mockUser?.nickname
        locationTv.text = mockUser?.location
        emailTv.text = mockUser?.email
        bioTv.text = mockUser?.bio




        var editButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.editBtn);
        editButton.setOnClickListener {
            editProfile();
        }
    }

    fun editProfile() {
        val intent = Intent(this@ShowProfileActivity,EditProfileActivity::class.java)
        if (mockUser != null) {
            intent.putExtra("group23.lab1.user_fullname", mockUser.fullname)
            intent.putExtra("group23.lab1.user_nickname", mockUser.nickname)
            intent.putExtra("group23.lab1.user_location", mockUser.location)
            intent.putExtra("group23.lab1.user_email", mockUser.email)
            intent.putExtra("group23.lab1.user_bio", mockUser.bio)
        }
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.show_profile_menu, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.menu_show_profile_edit -> {
                /*
                TODO start edit profile activity (check activity name)
                val intent = Intent(this, com.group23.lab1.EditProfileActivity::class.java).apply {
                    if (mockUser != null) {
                        putExtra("group23.lab1.user_fullname", mockUser.fullname)
                        putExtra("group23.lab1.user_nickname", mockUser.nickname)
                        putExtra("group23.lab1.user_location", mockUser.location)
                        putExtra("group23.lab1.user_email", mockUser.email)
                        putExtra("group23.lab1.user_bio", mockUser.bio)
                    }
                }
                startActivityForResult(intent)
                */
                Toast.makeText(this, "OPEN EDIT PROFILE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
}
```

Second Activity

```
class EditProfileActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var fullnameTv: TextView
    private lateinit var nicknameTv: TextView
    private lateinit var locationTv: TextView
    private lateinit var emailTv: TextView
    private lateinit var bioTv: TextView



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile)

        val intent = intent

        fullnameTv = intent.getStringExtra("group23.lab1.user_fullname") //Type miss match error required textView but got String ?? 




        print(fullnameTv+" testt");

 }
}
```

Comment: Why do want to pass a TextView to SecondActivity?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string from FirstActivity to your SecondActivity which is the correct approach.

In your SecondActivity receive that string and set it in your TextView.

```
val fullName = intent.getStringExtra("group23.lab1.user_fullname")
fullnameTv.text = fullName
```

Answer (score 0):

You define `fullnameTv` as `TextView`, but the intent extra contains `string`, that's why the two types are mismatched.
What you want to do is to set the textview's text property - `fullnameTv.text = intent.getStringExtra("group23.lab1.user_fullname")`